# Cosmos DB returning 404

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am connecting my new Cosmos DB successfully.

```
private async Task InitialiseDb()
        {
            client = new CosmosClient(cosmosUrl, cosmosKey);
            database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
            container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync("MyContainer", "/id");
        }
```

I then manage to populate an item to my Cosmos instance.

```
 var response = await container.CreateItemAsync(myDocument);
```

When logging in to Azure and looking at my items, I seer the item. So it's stored.

now I am trying to get the item back, but get an error about `not found`.

> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not
> indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 0; ActivityId:
> e90da49c-510e-4940-a888-9531427a3810; Reason: ( Errors : [   "Resource
> Not Found. Learn more: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found" ] );

My method to get the item is pretty simple:

```
public async Task<MyDto> GetRecord(Guid myId)
        {
            var data = await container.ReadItemAsync<FlightDoc>(myId.ToString(), new PartitionKey("id"));
            return new MyDto
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse(data.Resource.id)
            };
            
        }
```

I think I am misunderstanding the partition and how that works. Is there anything obviously wrong? Here's a partial screenshot of my data explorer:

[image]

I am passing the ID showing in the Id above.

Edit: Better explanation of data. The Flight, wholes a lot of Samples. A flight has many samples... Each sample has an Id. But I am trying to bring back the Flgith, with the Samples.

[image]

Comment: So did you read through https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found

Comment: what is the value of myId?

Comment: @Sajeetharan - it's the same as the "id" field in the screenshot. (Sorry, I just deleted and recreated the container so I can't copy and paste it). In the list (In Data Explorer), the "id" field in the document, is the same as ith "id" in the left of items (As shown above). which is the same as the /id field in the list. That's the Id I pass in.

Comment: @Craig Change this line ```var data = await container.ReadItemAsync<FlightDoc>(myId.ToString(), new PartitionKey("id"));``` to ```var data = await container.ReadItemAsync<FlightDoc>(myId.ToString(), new PartitionKey(myId.ToString()));``` to have a try.

Comment: @SteveZhao - That worked! I have completely misunderstood how that line works, it seems. It doesn't make sense to me now, so I'll read further, but thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just noticed the code, you need to pass the partition key value instead of the partition key in the code

```
var data = await container.ReadItemAsync<FlightDoc>(myId.ToString(), new PartitionKey(myId.ToString()));
```

Comment: FYI This exact type of question has been answered several times. Probably best to close as a duplicate of any of them, rather than posting another one... (or close as "typo or could not reproduce")

Comment: Note: I closed this question as duplicate. The question I added as duplicate is near-identical, as is the accepted answer.